# WPF on Rendering Tier 2 machine still using Software Rendering

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gpu

I have a WPF application in which I put a check for the rendering tier and on my dev machine it reports Tier 2 every time. As far as I know this means that it has full hardware rendering capability.  Which it should, it's a new system running an Nvidia 550M chip.  But when I check with WPFPerf, it shows that the entire app is rendering in software mode!  What can I check to figure out what is causing this?

One thought is could it be that I have AllowTransparancy set to True? (It's a borderless window, so I had to use it).

Answer (score 0):

NVidia 555M? That sounds like [Optimus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus) issue. I had this issue with some games - the GPU-chooser doesn't detect a performance intensive application and runs it on the GPU integrated in CPU.

I never had this issue with a WPF app though (I think the integrated GPU should be tier 2 as well, at least it appears to be on my Core i7).

Try going to NVidia Control Panel -> Manage 3D Settings -> add your application there. If you are using VS debugger, add the X.vshost.exe as well.

Comment: Did that already as well... And also confirmed that both the integrated and the Nvidia chip are Tier 2.  But even when adding my app to use the Nvidia chip, it still software renders.